# Visitas ao website

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: banco de dados]

Olá amigos possuo essas informações dos meus visitantes para fazer uma Dashboard bem bacana, estou querendo calcular o tempo de permanência dos clientes no site, a cada acesso que a pessoa dá ele grava no banco de dados com isso temos o datetime, date e o time também separados. Penso em fazer uma consulta sql que assume que se houver um acesso em um período posterior de 1h de um registro para outro conta como outra visita se tiver os registros do mesmo ip em um intervalo menor de 1h é a mesma visita ao website. Tem como fazer isso via mysql ?

Comment: Tu poderia criar alguma função que dispare um update pegando a hora que entrou e adicionando +5 minutos de 5 em 5 minutos...

Comment: ótima ideia, fazer uma consulta para ver se existe o registro do cliente e se segue ao padrão desejado, vou mudar essa regra. Obrigado

Comment: Problema resolvido amigo muito obrigado